# Docker: Run MySQL Server 4.1.22 or 4.1.21

Tags: mysql, docker

We have POS software which use only MySQL 4.1.22 or 4.1.21. We cant install on cloud that version. It is possible to do that with Docker?

We found one container but not working:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER Steve Mayne <steve.mayne@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y \
  bison \
  build-essential \ 
  checkinstall \
  libncurses5-dev 

ADD mysql-4.1.25.tar.gz /usr/local/src
COPY buildmysql4.sh /tmp/buildmysql4.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/buildmysql4.sh
RUN /tmp/buildmysql4.sh

FROM ubuntu:12.04

ENV PATH /usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
ENV MYSQLDATA /usr/local/mysql/var
VOLUME /usr/local/mysql/var

COPY --from=0 /usr/local/src/mysql-4.1.25/mysql_4.1.25-1_amd64.deb /tmp/mysql_4.1.25-1_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i /tmp/mysql_4.1.25-1_amd64.deb && rm /tmp/mysql_4.1.25-1_amd64.deb
COPY my.cnf /etc/my.cnf
RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql
RUN chown -R root /usr/local/mysql && chown -R mysql /usr/local/mysql/var && chgrp -R mysql /usr/local/mysql 

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 3306

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mysqld_safe"]
```

Is possible to start 4.1.21 version with docker?
Thanks

**Update**

```
root@galen-cloud-lamp-ubuntu-4gb-hel1-1:~/mysql4# docker run -it mysql -p 3306:3306
set -eo pipefail
+ set -eo pipefail

if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
  set -- mysqld_safe "$@"
fi
+ [ - = - ]
+ set -- mysqld_safe -p 3306:3306

HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
+ hostname
+ HOSTNAME=f3584f6d9133

file_env() {
  var=$1
  file_var="${var}_FILE"
  var_value=$(printenv $var || true)
  file_var_value=$(printenv $file_var || true)
  default_value=$2

  if [ -n "$var_value" -a -n "$file_var_value" ]; then
    echo >&2 "error: both $var and $file_var are set (but are exclusive)"
    exit 1
  fi

  if [ -z "${var_value}" ]; then
    if [ -z "${file_var_value}" ]; then
      export "${var}"="${default_value}"
    else
      export "${var}"="${file_var_value}"
    fi
  fi

  unset "$file_var"
}

_get_config() {
  conf="$1"
  mysqld_safe --help > /dev/null
  cat /etc/my.cnf | grep -i 'datadir=' | cut -d '=' -f 2
}

DATA_DIR="$(_get_config 'datadir')"
+ _get_config datadir
+ conf=datadir
+ mysqld_safe --help
+ cat /etc/my.cnf
+ cut -d = -f 2
+ grep -i datadir=
+ DATA_DIR=/var/db/mysql

if [ ! -d "${DATA_DIR}tmp" ]; then
        mkdir "${DATA_DIR}tmp"
        chown mysql:mysql  "${DATA_DIR}/tmp"
fi
+ [ ! -d /var/db/mysqltmp ]
+ mkdir /var/db/mysqltmp
+ chown mysql:mysql /var/db/mysql/tmp
if [ ! -d "${DATA_DIR}mysql" ]; then
  file_env 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'
  if [ -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo >&2 'error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified '
    echo >&2 '  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD'
    exit 1
  fi

  echo $"$DATA_DIR"
  mkdir -p "$DATA_DIR"
  chown mysql: "$DATA_DIR"

  echo 'Initializing database'
  mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir="$DATA_DIR" --rpm
  chown -R mysql: "$DATA_DIR"
  echo 'Database initialized'

  tfile=`mktemp`
  if [ ! -f "$tfile" ]; then
      return 1
  fi

  cat << EOF > $tfile
USE mysql;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("") WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
EOF

  if [ "$MYSQL_DATABASE" != "" ]; then
    echo "[i] Creating database: $MYSQL_DATABASE"
    echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;" >> $tfile

    if [ "$MYSQL_USER" != "" ]; then
      echo "[i] Creating user: $MYSQL_USER with password $MYSQL_PASSWORD"
      echo "GRANT ALL ON \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\`.* to '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_PASSWORD';" >> $tfile
    fi
  fi

  mysqld_safe --user=root --bootstrap --datadir="$DATA_DIR" < $tfile
fi
+ [ ! -d /var/db/mysqlmysql ]
+ file_env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
+ var=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
+ file_var=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE
+ printenv MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
+ true
+ var_value=
+ printenv MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE
+ true
+ file_var_value=
+ default_value=
+ [ -n  -a -n  ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ export MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
+ unset MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE
+ [ -z  -a -z  -a -z  ]
+ echo error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
+ echo   You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
+ exit 1
```

**Update 2**

```
root@galen-cloud-lamp-ubuntu-4gb-hel1-1:~/mysql4# docker run -it mysql -p 3306:3306
set -eo pipefail
+ set -eo pipefail

if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
  set -- mysqld_safe "$@"
fi
+ [ - = - ]
+ set -- mysqld_safe -p 3306:3306

HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
+ hostname
+ HOSTNAME=3d5c289cb9ca

file_env() {
  var=$1
  file_var="${var}_FILE"
  var_value=$(printenv $var || true)
  file_var_value=$(printenv $file_var || true)
  default_value=$2

  if [ -n "$var_value" -a -n "$file_var_value" ]; then
    echo >&2 "error: both $var and $file_var are set (but are exclusive)"
    exit 1
  fi

  if [ -z "${var_value}" ]; then
    if [ -z "${file_var_value}" ]; then
      export "${var}"="${default_value}"
    else
      export "${var}"="${file_var_value}"
    fi
  fi

  unset "$file_var"
}

_get_config() {
  conf="$1"
  mysqld_safe --help > /dev/null
  cat /etc/my.cnf | grep -i 'datadir=' | cut -d '=' -f 2
}

DATA_DIR="$(_get_config 'datadir')"
+ _get_config datadir
+ conf=datadir
+ mysqld_safe --help
+ cat /etc/my.cnf
+ grep -i datadir=
+ cut -d = -f 2
+ DATA_DIR=/var/db/mysql

if [ ! -d "${DATA_DIR}tmp" ]; then
        mkdir "${DATA_DIR}tmp"
        chown mysql:mysql  "${DATA_DIR}/tmp"
fi
+ [ ! -d /var/db/mysqltmp ]
+ mkdir /var/db/mysqltmp
+ chown mysql:mysql /var/db/mysql/tmp
if [ ! -d "${DATA_DIR}mysql" ]; then
  file_env 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'
  if [ -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo >&2 'error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified '
    echo >&2 '  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD'
    exit 1
  fi

  echo $"$DATA_DIR"
  mkdir -p "$DATA_DIR"
  chown mysql: "$DATA_DIR"

  echo 'Initializing database'
  mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir="$DATA_DIR" --rpm
  chown -R mysql: "$DATA_DIR"
  echo 'Database initialized'

  tfile=`mktemp`
  if [ ! -f "$tfile" ]; then
      return 1
  fi

  cat << EOF > $tfile
USE mysql;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("") WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
EOF

  if [ "$MYSQL_DATABASE" != "" ]; then
    echo "[i] Creating database: $MYSQL_DATABASE"
    echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;" >> $tfile

    if [ "$MYSQL_USER" != "" ]; then
      echo "[i] Creating user: $MYSQL_USER with password $MYSQL_PASSWORD"
      echo "GRANT ALL ON \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\`.* to '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_PASSWORD';" >> $tfile
    fi
  fi

  mysqld_safe --user=root --bootstrap --datadir="$DATA_DIR" < $tfile
fi
+ [ ! -d /var/db/mysqlmysql ]
+ file_env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
+ var=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
+ file_var=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE
+ printenv MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
+ var_value=dadule1589
+ printenv MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE
+ true
+ file_var_value=
+ default_value=
+ [ -n dadule1589 -a -n  ]
+ [ -z dadule1589 ]
+ unset MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE
+ [ -z dadule1589 -a -z  -a -z  ]
+ echo $/var/db/mysql
$/var/db/mysql
+ mkdir -p /var/db/mysql
+ chown mysql: /var/db/mysql
+ echo Initializing database
Initializing database
+ mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/db/mysql --rpm
PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:
/usr/local/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
/usr/local/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h 3d5c289cb9ca password 'new-password'
See the manual for more instructions.

Please report any problems with the /usr/local/bin/mysqlbug script!

The latest information about MySQL is available on the web at
http://www.mysql.com
Support MySQL by buying support/licenses at http://shop.mysql.com
+ chown -R mysql: /var/db/mysql
+ echo Database initialized
Database initialized
+ mktemp
+ tfile=/tmp/tmp.Mnobfk
+ [ ! -f /tmp/tmp.Mnobfk ]
+ cat
+ [  !=  ]
+ mysqld_safe --user=root --bootstrap --datadir=/var/db/mysql
Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/db/mysql
STOPPING server from pid file /var/db/mysql/3d5c289cb9ca.pid
230617 20:13:05  mysqld ended


chown -R mysql: "$DATA_DIR"
+ chown -R mysql: /var/db/mysql
exec "$@"+ exec mysqld_safe -p 3306:3306
Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/db/mysql
STOPPING server from pid file /var/db/mysql/3d5c289cb9ca.pid
230617 20:13:05  mysqld ended
```

Comment: define "not working", and see: https://github.com/andrebossi/mysql4 (which is not even 2 years old, which is pretty new for a 4.1.21 database)

Comment: I found that repo but how can install git repo on cloud?

Comment: Sorry, but [cloud](https://www.nasa.gov/audience/forstudents/5-8/features/nasa-knows/what-are-clouds-58.html) is a pretty broad definition (), and I do not have enough experience to give the full explanation for you...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old version of MySQL and there are no official image for such version.

So you have to use custom Dockerfile like the following (also present in the comment) `git@github.com:andrebossi/mysql4.git`.

Then the steps are to download it locally

```
git clone git@github.com:andrebossi/mysql4.git
cd mysql4
```

Create the image:

```
docker build -t mysql .
```

Run it and expose and open the port:

```
docker run -it mysql -p 3306:3306
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I do what you say and install it. After creating image i try `docker run` and check my update above in question. Where i need to define user and pass now?

Comment: It depend on how the Dockerfile has been created. In general , you set user and password through environmental variables. For example, in this case, you need to add the variable in the Dockerfile the line `ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=default-pwd` that contains the default value, then build the image with `docker build`, and finally (if you want to overwrite the default value) set the env variable in the docker run `docker run -it mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="my-pwd"`.

Comment: Where is stored that Dockerfile? How to access with nano editor?

Comment: You download it with the `git clone` command and edit it through an editor like vim/nano

Comment: I do that check update  3 in question